# Apache Beam - how to split a PCollection into 2 by key in Python

Tags: python, apache-beam

Suppose we have 2 PCollections:

PCollection 1:

```
[<ID_1, some_data>, <ID_2, some_data>, ... <ID_5, some_data>]
```

PCollection 2:

```
[<ID_2>, <ID_5>]
```

Both PCollections are bounded, but can be huge (so prefer no side input).

Say we want to split PCollection1 into 2, decided by whether the ID_x exists in PCollection 2, i.e. one PCollection will have 
`[<ID_1, some_data>, <ID_3, some_data>, <ID_4, some_data>]` and another `[<ID_2, some_data>, <ID_5, some_data>]`. How to achieve this?

It seems that `Partition` transform is the way to go but I cannot figure out how.

But the way, I am using Python.

Answer (score 1):

`Partition` will allow you to actually split one `PCollection` into multiple based on criteria that you should be able to calculate at run-time, so in theory it can be used for this. But in your case the criteria is "ID exists in pcollection_of_ids". So you need to be able to perform this check more or less efficiently.

I don't believe there's a single definitive solution to this, it depends on specifics of your setup and data. E.g. how huge are the input `PCollections`? Or what if you received an element in `pcollection1` while there was no matching ID in `pcollection_of_ids`, but then matching ID appeared there after you have already split the input? Or, can you preload your IDs into some service for efficient key/value lookups? Or save it into such service in a separate parallel pipeline while IDs come in?

Comment: Thanks @Anton. I have successfully implemented the case where PCollection2 is small and as side input. In my case, I can defer the processing until PCollection2 is computed (it is bounded in size), but the concern is it can be huge - assume PCollection1 in in order of million of billion rows and PCollection2 can contain billions of IDs.

Comment: But now thinking about it, to make filtering works in parallel (e.g. side input), copying the whole PCollection2 over to workers may be inevitable. But is there a better way that I do not know?